# how can i find a currency text in a column and multiply it by my own conversion rate using excel function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Lets say i have the following in excel

```
                                              Self determine exchange rate
          A             |         B
```

1   Other currencies             |   USD
2   EUR 111
3   POUNDS 222

D1:EUR    1.6 D2: POUNDS  2.0

how can i make use of the excel function to find the currency text example "EUR" in column A and do multiplcation between a exchange rate i entered in column D1 with the integer value in A2? same for other currencies, if "POUNDS" is detected instead of "EUR" it will multiply the integer value in A3 with D2 and display at B2.

Comment: why do you have to store numbers as text including currency instead of indicating currency in different column?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a look-up. Usually one uses a database for such task.

If you have currency name and amount in different cells, you could use [vlookup function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) to find exchange rate in a standalone group of cells. Then it should be easy to put result of conversion in yet another cell. Just remember to use `$` sign to prevent iterations in the arguments of vlookup call (you have a fixed group of cells with conversion rates) when you applying formula to adjacent cells.

If you have both currency name and amount in a single cell, then it is highly advisable to split those. Either [using GUI](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214261) or with [some function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/split-text-among-columns-by-using-functions-HA010102341.aspx).